# PHP y su comportamiento con clases

Tags: php

He creado unos modelos que extienden todos de un ModeloBase, aunque cos atributos estan en cada hijo, He creado un DaoBase para las operaciones comunes, y heredan los distintos Daos, todo con PDO, y ahora el problema. Al leer un registro, parte de los datos quedan en atributos que marca como de ModeloBase, aunque este no tiene ninguno. Este es el var_dump del objeto leido. Observad los ultimos campos...que nunca existieron en el Base.

> object(modelos\Imagen)#6 (15) {
>     ["imagen_id":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     string(2) "27"
>     ["imagen_nombre":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     string(23) "2018-10-03_23h00_31.png"
>     ["imagen_tiempo":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     string(1) "6"
>     ["imagen_orden":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     string(1) "1"
>     ["imagen_pertenencia":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     string(1) "L"
>     ["imagen_valor":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     string(1) "2"
>     ["imagen_horaInicio":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     NULL
>     ["imagen_horaFin":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     NULL
>     ["imagen_dias":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     string(1) "*"
>     ["imagen_caduca":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     string(19) "2019-12-02 00:00:00"
>     ["imagen_lastUpdate":"modelos\Imagen":private]=>
>     NULL
>     ["modelo":"modelos\ModeloBase":private]=>
>     string(6) "Imagen"
>     ["imagen_horainicio"]=>
>     string(8) "01:01:00"
>     ["imagen_horafin"]=>
>     string(8) "22:00:00"
>     ["imagen_lastupdate"]=>
>     string(10) "2018-12-02"

Clase ModeloBase

```
<?php
namespace modelos;
require_once (KIOSKO_RAIZ . 'service/RutinasXml.php');
use service\RutinasXml;

abstract Class  ModeloBase
{
    private $modelo;

    public function __construct(string $modelo){
        $this->setModelo($modelo);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getModelo()
    {
        return $this->modelo;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $modelo
     */
    public function setModelo($modelo)
    {
        $this->modelo = $modelo;
    }

    public abstract function getId():int;
    public abstract function setId(int $id_valor):void;

    public function getXml(): string
    {
        $miXML=RutinasXml::arrayToXML($this->getArray(), $this->getModelo());
        return $miXML;
    }
}
```

Clase Imagen

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace modelos;

use DateTime;
require_once (KIOSKO_RAIZ . 'modelos/ModeloBase.php');

class Imagen extends ModeloBase
{

    private $imagen_id;

    private $imagen_nombre;

    private $imagen_tiempo;

    private $imagen_orden;

    private $imagen_pertenencia;

    // G-grupo, C-cliente, L-Local
    private $imagen_valor;

    private $imagen_horaInicio;

    private $imagen_horaFin;

    // *,Lu,Ma,Mie,Ju,Vi,Sa,Do
    private $imagen_dias;


    private $imagen_caduca;

    // Dia y hora
    private $imagen_lastUpdate;

    public function __construct(int $imagen_id = null, string $imagen_nombre = null, int $imagen_tiempo = null, int $imagen_orden = null, string $imagen_pertenencia = null, int $imagen_valor = null, int $imagen_horaInicio = null, int $imagen_horaFin = null, string $imagen_dias = null, int $imagen_caduca = null, int $imagen_lastUpdate = null)
    {
        parent::__construct("Imagen");
        if (func_num_args() > 0) {
            $this->setImagen_id($imagen_id);
            $this->setImagen_nombre($imagen_nombre);
            $this->setImagen_tiempo($imagen_tiempo);
            $this->setImagen_orden($imagen_orden);
            $this->setImagen_pertenencia($imagen_pertenencia);
            $this->setImagen_valor($imagen_valor);
            $this->setImagen_horaInicio($imagen_horaInicio);
            $this->setImagen_horaFin($imagen_horaFin);
            $this->setImagen_dias($imagen_dias);
            $this->setImagen_caduca($imagen_caduca);
            $this->setImagen_lastUpdate($imagen_lastUpdate);
        }
    }
```

....
El var_dump

```
public function getImagen_horaFin_String(): String
    {

          //echo "getHoraFin=";
          var_dump($this);

        if (null == $this->imagen_horaFin)
            return '23:00:00';
            return date(FORMATO_HORA, $this->imagen_horaFin);
    }
    ...

DaoImagen:
  function listxTipo(string $tipo,int $valor):array
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(static::SELECT_TIPO);
        $stmt->bindValue(':imagen_pertenencia', $tipo);
        $stmt->bindValue(':imagen_valor', $valor);

        $lista = $this->acceder($stmt);

        return $lista;
    }

DaoBase

    function acceder(PDOStatement $stmt):array
    {
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS ,  $this->modelo );
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que en el var_dump en ModeloBase, aparecen cargados pero con los nombres de campo en minuscula (imagen_horainicio, imagen_hotafin, imagen_lastupdate) sin embargo en la base de datos estan en mayusculas, y los select son selec

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿De donde sacas el `var_dump`? ¿Estás mapeando el resultado de la consulta a una clase en concreto? ¿A cual?

Comment: Recupero sobre la clase modelos\Imagenes, que es hija de modelos\ModeloBase. y el var_dump es despues de la lectura. Lo curioso es que esto lo hace con tres campos nuevos, que añadi a modelos\Imagenes algun tiempo despues, ...pero no existen en ningun sitio

Comment: Pero ¿en la consulta seleccionas esos campos?

Comment: select *. y ademas si te fijas en las ultimas 6 lineas compartidas, veras que se llenan, pero en un sitio extraño

Comment: Los datos que dices que no existen en la clase pero que se crean, son columnas que existen en tu `SELECT`, pero que no has declarado en la clase donde mapeas los resultados. No lo puedo confirmar a ciencia cierta, pero en ese caso PDO crea propiedades nuevas cuando alguna columna del `SELECT` no existe en la clase.

Comment: Ante todo, gracias por contestarme. En la clase hija, Imagenes, estan TODOS los campos definidos; observa el var_dump. en la clase padre, no se define NINGUN campo, sin embargo, en el var_dump. aparecen los tres, con minusculas. Esos campos, con minusculas no estan en la BBDD..De ahi mi asombro

Comment: Si pones el código que estás usando y el de las clases quizá podamos entendernos mejor. El `var_dump` es el resultado de ***algo***, hay que ver cómo estás haciendo ese ***algo***, para poderte ayudar a ver el problema.

Comment: Lo veo logico, el problema es ¿como lo publico?
Imagenes es un modelo; atributos, getter y setter tienen sobre 400 lineas,
ModeloBase, sobre 35 lineas.
Si ademas publico DaoBase y DaoImagens, 500 lineas mas....

Comment: Muy simple: [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/218890/edit) agregando debajo el código.  Eso sí, no pongas miles de línea de código aquí, solo las clases implicadas y el código PHP donde mapeas los resultados.

Comment: cambia: public function setModelo($modelo)
    {
        $this->modelo = $modelo;
    }
por : 
public function setModelo($atributo, $modelo){
   $this->$atributo = $modelo;
  }
ya que para llamar a un attributo estas seteando a imagen_loquesea = imagen_loquesea y deberia ser imagen_id = imagen_loquesea; setModelo("imagen_id","imagen_loquesea"); y luego un getModelo("imagen_id");

Comment: Creo que todo el problema viene de que en MySQL los nombres de columna no respetan mayusculas y minusculas, como en la clase Imagen los tengo en CamenCase, no los reconoce y crea nuevas apariciones.... Estoy probandolo

Comment: Resuelto. MySql carga los campos siempre en minuscula....si has puesto los atributos en mayusculas o CamelCase, no los encuentra y crea otros